# Visual Studio me da error al compilar, pero no me muestra el error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra el mensaje de erorr de compilación, pero no me muestra el error, como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? ¿Qué mensaje recibes? Ve a la ventana de Salida y mira si hay algún error de compilación. Es raro lo que describes.

Comment: No recibo ningún mensaje. Y tampoco me muestra ningún error de compilación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde consola y el directorio del proyecto ejecuta el comando:

```
dotnet build
```

Esto en teoría repara el proyecto , lo compila y te muestra los errores

Answer (score 0):

yo lo pude solucionar haciendo lo siguiente.

En la solución del proyecto hice click derecho, Limpiar Solucion y luego compile de vuelta. Eso soluciono ese problema.